# Extracting data form website using php

Tags: php, regex

I have the following website:
http://stationmeteo.meteorologic.net/metar/your-metar.php?icao=LFRS&day=070308

I want to extract data from it.
I tried using file_get_contents and some regular expressions, but something is not working.

this is the code I tried:

```
$content=file_get_contents('http://stationmeteo.meteorologic.net/metar/your-metar.php? icao=LFMN&day=010513');

preg_match('/00\:30 07\/03\/2008(.+)01\:30 07\/03\/2008/',$content,$m);
echo $m[0];
echo $m[1];
```

It's giving me undefined offset 0 and 1.
If I copy the content of the web page directly to $content instead of using file_get_contents, it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: When your using `file_get_contents(...)`, what are your getting in $content ?

Comment: You're getting no matches because there's no timestamps that match `00:00 01/05/2013`?

Comment: sorry I set the date wrong I mean, 00:30 07/03/2008 and 01:30 07/03/2008

Comment: Is `file_get_contents` returning something at all?

Comment: yes, if I echo $content, it will return the content of the website.

Comment: This is not actually a website, it's a plain text file. And that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.+` matches any characters except newlines, and there is a newline character in the text you're trying to match.

Try

```
preg_match('~00:30 07/03/2008(.+)01:30 07/03/2008~s',$content,$m);
```

(using `~` as a delimiter so you don't have to escape all those slashes, by the way)

The next question is: Why don't I get this problem when copying the contents of the webpage directly into `$content`? Well, all whitespace is normalized to a single space when a webpage is rendered, turning the `\n` that's present in the page's source code (press Ctrl-U to see it) into a simple space. And `.+` matches that space.

Comment: Ok, now I understood what was going on.
and thx for the ~ delimiter tip. (really helpful)